# Odd behavior with 3 TextViews inside a TableRow

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having an issue with my layout and I can't seem to find why this issue is happening.

I have 3 TextViews, and I want them all evenly spaced, side by side. I have each of their `weight` set to `1` but they are not behaving as expected.

[Here is an image of what I am talking about.](http://gyazo.com/3a06c0b3004b0e4c68f79abb508d7abd) You can see that they do not line up for some odd reason, despite the same properties on each.

Below is the XML for the TableRow in question.

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3"
        />

</TableRow>
```

Comment: I think you should define the orientation of TableRow and 0dp of TextView's layout_width.

Comment: The image seems to be lined up and as suggested by @Mitsuaki all you need to do is explicity specify the width to be 0dp. If this is not your requirement,Kindly specify the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

The link to the image you posted seems evenly spaced, side by side! Though the text is aligned to left of the text view. Add `android:weightSum="3"` in TableRow and set `android:gravity="center"` in TextView. It might help!

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3" />
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

replace your code with :

```
  android:layout_width="0dp"
```

cheers/.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Use this..may it helps you


                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/details"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/list_divider"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:stretchColumns="*" >

                        <TableRow
                            android:id="@+id/row3"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/lot"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/discout_singleview"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/pricelot"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:background="@color/list_divider" />
                    </TableLayout>
```